# Can not initiate checkout page successfully using pay with amazon v2

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-pay

[checkout page popup error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxC7b.png)
I am integrating pay with amazon button in angular application. Got error code but not error message. Cant understand whats going wrong.

**Payload**

```
this.payload = {
      "webCheckoutDetails": {
        "checkoutReviewReturnUrl": "environment.checkoutReviewReturnUrl"
      },
      "storeId": environment.awsClientId,
      "scopes": ["profile", "pin_codes", "phoneNumber"],
      "chargePermissionType": "Recurring",
      "recurringMetadata": {
        "frequency": {
          "unit": this.plan.NewPlan.Frequency,
          "value": this.plan.NewPlan.Frequency_Interval,
        },
        "amount": {
          "amount": this.plan.NewPlan.Price,
          "currencyCode": "USD"
        }
      }
    };
```

**Button**

```
amazon.Pay.renderButton('#AmazonPayButton', {
      // set checkout environment
      merchantId: environment.awsSellerId,
      publicKeyId: environment.publicKeyId,
      ledgerCurrency: 'USD',
      // customize the buyer experience
      checkoutLanguage: 'en_US',
      productType: 'PayOnly',
      placement: 'Cart',
      // configure Create Checkout Session request
      createCheckoutSessionConfig: {
        payloadJSON: JSON.stringify(this.payload),
        signature: this.signature,
        algorithm: this.algorithm
      }
    });

  }
```

**FYI**:Script and button is loaded successfully.

Update: I resolved the problem. My code has a server-side function that creates a signature. This function takes some time to finish, and the button was rendered before the signature. I fixed it by making sure the button is rendered after the signature is created.

Comment: I think this is the problem  "checkoutReviewReturnUrl": "environment.checkoutReviewReturnUrl". You pass the environment URL as a string.

Comment: Hey I can't reveal URL so here I showed it as variable. otherwise in my code i have provided it as a string like: "https://www.google.com/".

Comment: @dhruv14 Is your return url complete with `https://`?

Comment: @dhruv14 Also important: `merchantId` for the button and `storeId` in the payload seem to be the same in your code. They are in fact different values.

Comment: @marcus.kreusch https://www.example.com/review.html

Comment: @dhruv14 If you like, you can send me the actual values you are sending via email for debugging

Comment: @dhruv14 It should be `https://example.com/review.html`

Comment: @marcus.kreusch I am sure about store id, how can i get merchantId

Comment: @dhruv14 Easiest way for the merchantId is the Integration Central page (https://sellercentral.amazon.de/gp/pyop/seller/integrationcentral/): https://i.imgur.com/RaM1Ugx.png

Comment: @marcus.kreusch Hey, I updated both URL and merchant id, still getting same error.